# Yocto device tree overlay

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, yocto, bitbake

I am working on a Beaglebone Black, using Yocto.

Using [this](https://github.com/SaadAhmad/beaglebone-black-cpp-PWM) implementation of a PWM driver as a guide, I am unable to add my PWMs to the device tree.

The best solution would be to create a device tree overlay as Mr. Saad Ahmad is doing, but I don't understand how to do this using Yocto.

I am not using *capemgr*, but I am using [meta-bbb](https://github.com/jumpnow/meta-bbb). I also have custom layer *meta-tfe* which currently holds the pwm-driver and some examples. This layer also defines a new bitbake image recipe:

```
include recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb

IMAGE_INSTALL += "\
        helloworld \
        hellokernel \
        bbb-pwm \
"

KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "\
        hellokernel \
        bbb-pwm \
"

export IMAGE_BASENAME = "tfe-image-base"
```

Following is the .bb file of the pwm-driver:

```
DESCRIPTION = "PWM kernel module"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"

PR = "r0"

inherit module

SRC_URI = "file://bbb-pwm.c \
    file://Makefile \
    file://COPYING \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Edit**:
A colleague hinted that I could use a .bbappend file, appending to the kernel build-rules in meta-bbb. Hence this is what I did, and now my recipes-kernel directory now looks like this:

```
.
├── bbb-pwm
│   ├── bbb-pwm.bb
│   └── files
│       ├── bbb-pwm.c
│       ├── COPYING
│       └── Makefile
├── hellokernel
│   └── {...}
└── linux
    ├── linux-stable_4.1
    │   └── {...}
    ├── linux-stable_4.1.bbappend
    ├── linux-stable_4.4
    │   └── {...}
    ├── linux-stable_4.4.bbappend
    ├── linux-stable_4.5
    │   └── dts
    │       ├── bbb-pwm.dts
    │       └── sc_pwm_P8_13-00A0.dtsi
    └── linux-stable_4.5.bbappend
```

The directories linux-stable_4.*/ all have the same structure, to reflect the mirrored structure in meta-bbb.

My .bbappend files look like this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}/dts:"

KERNEL_DEVICETREE_beaglebone += " \
    bbb-pwm.dtb \
"
```

However, when bitbaking, an error occurs saying there are no build rules for bbb-pwm.dtb:

```
| make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/bbb-pwm.dtb'.  Stop.
| arch/arm/Makefile:333: recipe for target 'bbb-pwm.dtb' failed
```

*Edit*: Here is [sc_pwm_P8_13-00A0.dtsi](http://pastebin.com/4DUyAgdg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to use a custom device tree and edit the `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` variable, the device tree sources (*.dts files and *.dtsi files) are searched in `arch/arm/boot/dts` (according to your architecture).

In your example your files are placed in a separate folder and not fetched by the bbappend file. The correct layer structure would be following:

```
└── linux
    ├── linux-stable_4.5
    │   └── git
    │       └── arch
    │           └── arm
    │               └── boot
    │                   └── dts
    │                       ├── bbb-pwm.dts
    │                       └── sc_pwm_P8_13-00A0.dtsi
    └── linux-stable_4.5.bbappend
```

To make bitbake sensible for those new files they have to be added via the `SRC_URI` variable in the bbappend file:

```
SRC_URI += "file://git/arch/arm/boot/dts/bbb-pwm.dts"
SRC_URI += "file://git/arch/arm/boot/dts/sc_pwm_P8_13-00A0.dtsi"
```

Comment: Thanks. That kind of worked (had to change the path to git/arch/arm/boot/dts, will correct you answer to reflect this). This is however not very portable. Is there Yocto/OE variable that holds this path?

Comment: It's the default folder for device tree sources in the linux kernel. I doubt there is another solution since this is a fix place. Device-Tree can be used during runtime and so I guess it has to be there.

Comment: What's about the file already exists? Is there a way to force copy or do i have to make a patch?

Comment: @FranzForstmayr Both methods are possible. If you create a new file with identical filename your file has priority providing that your layer has a higher priority than the layer the other device tree file is located in.